# ios 10 Crash in Foundation while entering text (UITextView) on iPad - can't reproduce

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, crash

I have an odd situation where one user is repeatedly seeing crashes (on iPad 9.7 pro, under both iOS 10.0.1 and 10.0.2, not jailbroken) while entering text in a UITextField. The crash reports vary, but the most common crash is below.

I can't reproduce this or figure out what is going wrong. Any ideas on what to do or where to look to fix this? Could it be something unique to his environment? I asked the user to delete and reinstall the app, and he claims to have done so and the crashes are still happening. Thanks!

```
Platform: ios
Application: Next Turn
Version: 2.50 (2.12)
Issue #: 58
Date: 2016-09-25T09:19:33Z
OS Version: 10.0.2 (14A456)
Device: iPad Pro (9.7 inch)
RAM Free: 18.2% 
Disk Free: 89.7%

0. Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  ProofReader                    0x186da0624 ICfree + 60
1  ProofReader                    0x186d9da08 ICspl + 3860
2  ProofReader                    0x186d9da08 ICspl + 3860
3  ProofReader                    0x186d9c644 PRIcs + 376
4  ProofReader                    0x186da2dec PRword + 1180
5  ProofReader                    0x186e164e0 -[AppleSpell(Spelling) validateWordBuffer:length:connection:] + 180
6  ProofReader                    0x186e17154 -[AppleSpell(Spelling) validateWordBuffer:length:language:connection:sender:checkBase:checkDict:checkTemp:checkUser:checkNames:checkHyphens:checkIntercaps:checkOptions:forCorrection:depth:] + 820
7  ProofReader                    0x186e196a0 -[AppleSpell(Spelling) validateWordBuffer:length:language:connection:sender:checkBase:checkDict:checkTemp:checkUser:checkNames:checkHyphens:checkIntercaps:checkOptions:depth:] + 92
8  ProofReader                    0x186e19700 -[AppleSpell(Spelling) validateWordBuffer:length:language:connection:sender:checkBase:checkDict:checkTemp:checkNames:checkHyphens:checkIntercaps:checkOptions:depth:] + 84
9  ProofReader                    0x186e1a92c -[AppleSpell(Spelling) spellServer:findMisspelledWordInString:range:languages:topLanguages:orthography:checkOrthography:mutableResults:offset:autocorrect:onlyAtInsertionPoint:initialCapitalize:autocapitalize:keyEventArray:appIdentifier:selectedRangeValue:wordCount:countOnly:correction:] + 4364
10 ProofReader                    0x186db4cac -[AppleSpell spellServer:findMisspelledWordInString:languages:wordCount:countOnly:correction:] + 328
11 UIKit                          0x189cd7424 <redacted> + 156
12 UIKit                          0x189cd7924 <redacted> + 588
13 UIKit                          0x189cd7624 <redacted> + 116
14 UIKit                          0x189797ec0 <redacted> + 508
15 UIKit                          0x189797c5c <redacted> + 668
16 UIKit                          0x189797940 <redacted> + 32
17 UIKit                          0x189797910 <redacted> + 44
18 UIKit                          0x189793888 <redacted> + 4284
19 UIKit                          0x189bb483c <redacted> + 64
20 UIKit                          0x189bb7f44 <redacted> + 124
21 UIKit                          0x189779614 <redacted> + 260
22 UIKit                          0x189617b54 <redacted> + 764
23 UIKit                          0x189ba7f88 <redacted> + 1100
24 UIKit                          0x189ba7ae8 <redacted> + 408
25 UIKit                          0x189ba6da4 <redacted> + 268
26 UIKit                          0x189615d70 <redacted> + 2960
27 UIKit                          0x1895e6858 <redacted> + 340
28 UIKit                          0x189dd3cb8 <redacted> + 2736
29 UIKit                          0x189dcd720 <redacted> + 784
30 CoreFoundation                 0x183752278 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
31 CoreFoundation                 0x183751bc0 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 524
32 CoreFoundation                 0x18374f7c0 __CFRunLoopRun + 804
33 CoreFoundation                 0x18367e048 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
34 GraphicsServices               0x185101198 GSEventRunModal + 180
35 UIKit                          0x189651628 <redacted> + 684
36 UIKit                          0x18964c360 UIApplicationMain + 208
37 Next Turn                      0x1000b3f40 main (main.m:16)
38 libdispatch.dylib              0x1826605b8 (Missing)

--

#0. Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  ProofReader                    0x186da0624 ICfree + 60
1  ProofReader                    0x186d9da08 ICspl + 3860
2  ProofReader                    0x186d9da08 ICspl + 3860
3  ProofReader                    0x186d9c644 PRIcs + 376
4  ProofReader                    0x186da2dec PRword + 1180
5  ProofReader                    0x186e164e0 -[AppleSpell(Spelling) validateWordBuffer:length:connection:] + 180
6  ProofReader                    0x186e17154 -[AppleSpell(Spelling) validateWordBuffer:length:language:connection:sender:checkBase:checkDict:checkTemp:checkUser:checkNames:checkHyphens:checkIntercaps:checkOptions:forCorrection:depth:] + 820
7  ProofReader                    0x186e196a0 -[AppleSpell(Spelling) validateWordBuffer:length:language:connection:sender:checkBase:checkDict:checkTemp:checkUser:checkNames:checkHyphens:checkIntercaps:checkOptions:depth:] + 92
8  ProofReader                    0x186e19700 -[AppleSpell(Spelling) validateWordBuffer:length:language:connection:sender:checkBase:checkDict:checkTemp:checkNames:checkHyphens:checkIntercaps:checkOptions:depth:] + 84
9  ProofReader                    0x186e1a92c -[AppleSpell(Spelling) spellServer:findMisspelledWordInString:range:languages:topLanguages:orthography:checkOrthography:mutableResults:offset:autocorrect:onlyAtInsertionPoint:initialCapitalize:autocapitalize:keyEventArray:appIdentifier:selectedRangeValue:wordCount:countOnly:correction:] + 4364
10 ProofReader                    0x186db4cac -[AppleSpell spellServer:findMisspelledWordInString:languages:wordCount:countOnly:correction:] + 328
11 UIKit                          0x189cd7424 <redacted> + 156
12 UIKit                          0x189cd7924 <redacted> + 588
13 UIKit                          0x189cd7624 <redacted> + 116
14 UIKit                          0x189797ec0 <redacted> + 508
15 UIKit                          0x189797c5c <redacted> + 668
16 UIKit                          0x189797940 <redacted> + 32
17 UIKit                          0x189797910 <redacted> + 44
18 UIKit                          0x189793888 <redacted> + 4284
19 UIKit                          0x189bb483c <redacted> + 64
20 UIKit                          0x189bb7f44 <redacted> + 124
21 UIKit                          0x189779614 <redacted> + 260
22 UIKit                          0x189617b54 <redacted> + 764
23 UIKit                          0x189ba7f88 <redacted> + 1100
24 UIKit                          0x189ba7ae8 <redacted> + 408
25 UIKit                          0x189ba6da4 <redacted> + 268
26 UIKit                          0x189615d70 <redacted> + 2960
27 UIKit                          0x1895e6858 <redacted> + 340
28 UIKit                          0x189dd3cb8 <redacted> + 2736
29 UIKit                          0x189dcd720 <redacted> + 784
30 CoreFoundation                 0x183752278 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
31 CoreFoundation                 0x183751bc0 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 524
32 CoreFoundation                 0x18374f7c0 __CFRunLoopRun + 804
33 CoreFoundation                 0x18367e048 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
34 GraphicsServices               0x185101198 GSEventRunModal + 180
35 UIKit                          0x189651628 <redacted> + 684
36 UIKit                          0x18964c360 UIApplicationMain + 208
37 Next Turn                      0x1000b3f40 main (main.m:16)
38 libdispatch.dylib              0x1826605b8 (Missing)

#1. com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x18275416c mach_msg_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x182753fdc mach_msg + 72
2  CoreFoundation                 0x183751cec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192
3  CoreFoundation                 0x18374f908 __CFRunLoopRun + 1132
4  CoreFoundation                 0x18367e048 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
5  Foundation                     0x18418cb1c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304
6  Foundation                     0x1841ad60c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 96
7  UIKit                          0x189fc6c7c <redacted> + 136
8  Foundation                     0x18428a50c __NSThread__start__ + 1024
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x182837860 _pthread_body + 240
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x182837770 _pthread_body + 282
11 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x182834dbc thread_start + 4

#2. com.twitter.crashlytics.ios.MachExceptionServer
0  Next Turn                      0x10016b6d0 CLSProcessRecordAllThreads (CLSProcess.c:376)
1  Next Turn                      0x10016b6d0 CLSProcessRecordAllThreads (CLSProcess.c:376)
2  Next Turn                      0x10016baf0 CLSProcessRecordAllThreads (CLSProcess.c:403)
3  Next Turn                      0x10015c7d0 CLSHandler (CLSHandler.m:24)
4  Next Turn                      0x100157968 CLSMachExceptionServer (CLSMachException.c:443)
5  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x182837860 _pthread_body + 240
6  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x182837770 _pthread_body + 282
7  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x182834dbc thread_start + 4

#3. com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x18275416c mach_msg_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x182753fdc mach_msg + 72
2  CoreFoundation                 0x183751cec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192
3  CoreFoundation                 0x18374f908 __CFRunLoopRun + 1132
4  CoreFoundation                 0x18367e048 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
5  CFNetwork                      0x183e6bcec +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 336
6  Foundation                     0x18428a50c __NSThread__start__ + 1024
7  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x182837860 _pthread_body + 240
8  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x182837770 _pthread_body + 282
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x182834dbc thread_start + 4

#4. Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x182772a88 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18283536c _pthread_wqthread + 1452
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x182834db4 start_wqthread + 4

#5. Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x182772a88 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x182835188 _pthread_wqthread + 968
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x182834db4 start_wqthread + 4
```

Comment: I'm receiving similar crash reports when invoking UITextChecker manually. I assume it's yet another bug in iOS 10, as it worked without problems in iOS 9. Are you doing something to the text entered into the text field?

Comment: I saw the same log from a single user having four crashes.  This was on an iPad Pro 9.7", iPhone-only app, on iOS 10.2.  The only clue: a user -- presumably the same one -- asked about Smart Keyboard support.  He didn't mention a crash, but requested landscape support so that the keyboard could function.

Comment: I'm facing the same crash on iOS12